# Elasticsearch Couchdb River Monitor

Tags: couchdb, elasticsearch

I have a working River from Couchdb to Elasticsearch, everything works fine, but sometimes the River stop working and the only solution is to restart ES.

Is there a way to monitor the River to see if it's not updating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself by creating a ruby script that connects to Elasticsearch and Couchdb to gather the last sequence number. The number is compared and an alert is sent if the river is not working.

https://gist.github.com/McRipper/7657897